# EditorTemplate events do not fire

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, infragistics

I'm creating a WPF UserControl that wraps an Infragistics XamDataTree. As such, I am creating the layout(s) in code from my own XAML syntax (in this code, it's the `level`), as follows:

```
var layout = new NodeLayout
{
    Key = level.Description ?? level.NodeType.Name,
    TargetTypeName = level.NodeType.Name,
    IsExpandedMemberPath = level.IsExpandedMemberPath,
};

var itemTemplate = new DataTemplate(level.NodeType);
var stackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
stackPanelFactory.Name = level.NodeType.Name + "Factory";
stackPanelFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(level.IsCheckedMemberPath))
{
    var checkBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
    checkBoxFactory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("Data." + level.IsCheckedMemberPath));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(level.IsCheckableMemberPath))
        checkBoxFactory.SetBinding(IsEnabledProperty, new Binding("Data." + level.IsCheckableMemberPath));
    stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(checkBoxFactory);
}

var textBlockFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textBlockFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Data.Name"));
textBlockFactory.AddHandler(ToolTipOpeningEvent, new ToolTipEventHandler(HandleTextBlockToolTipOpening), true);
textBlockFactory.AddHandler(ToolTipClosingEvent, new ToolTipEventHandler(HandleTextBlockToolTipClosing), true);
textBlockFactory.SetValue(ToolTipProperty, " "); // need some value in there to trigger the event

stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(textBlockFactory);

itemTemplate.VisualTree = stackPanelFactory;
layout.ItemTemplate = itemTemplate;

if (level.AllowEdit)
{
    layout.EditingSettings.AllowDeletion = false;
    layout.EditingSettings.AllowEditing = true;
    layout.EditingSettings.IsEnterKeyEditingEnabled = false;
    layout.EditingSettings.IsF2EditingEnabled = true;
    layout.EditingSettings.IsMouseActionEditingEnabled = TreeMouseEditingAction.DoubleClick;
    layout.EditingSettings.IsOnNodeActiveEditingEnabled = false;

    var editTemplate = new DataTemplate(level.NodeType);
    var editStackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
    editStackPanelFactory.Name = level.NodeType.Name + "EditFactory";
    editStackPanelFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
    var textBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
    textBoxFactory.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Data.Name") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
    textBoxFactory.AddHandler(TextBox.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectAll), true);
    textBoxFactory.AddHandler(TextBox.TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(Target), true);
    editStackPanelFactory.AppendChild(textBoxFactory);
    editTemplate.VisualTree = editStackPanelFactory;
    editTemplate.Seal();
    layout.EditorTemplate = editTemplate;
}
Tree.GlobalNodeLayouts.Add(layout);
```

Editing works, the events on the `TextBlock` are thrown properly, but none of the events on the `TextBox` fire. Ever. Is it something I'm doing, a restriction on `EditorTemplate`, a quirk on `XamDataTree`... does this look familiar to anyone?

(Also adding this because it encapsulates a lot of other quirks there's almost no Google-juice whatsoever for, and might help people out no matter what... crucial items are `Mode = TwoWay`, the `Seal()` call, the blank setter to `ToolTip`, the order of `VisualTree` assignments... to put it another way, the above snippet represents 3 days of work.)

Comment: Can you create and show a test project to recreate the problem? By excerpt code hard to say what it is.

Comment: Why don't you simply monitor the Data.Name for INotifyPropertyChanged? It is not a solution, rather a work-around which should work, no? :)

Comment: I agree with @AnatoliyNikolaev. Can you provide a test project please

Comment: I think the issue is that events are not hooked when one uses LoadContent of the DataTemplate.

Comment: Couldn't it be that your `if (level.AllowEdit)` is never true?

Comment: Just stop doing this unreadable stuff:'code'
var layout = new NodeLayout
{
    Key = level.Description ?? level.NodeType.Name,
    TargetTypeName = level.NodeType.Name,
    IsExpandedMemberPath = level.IsExpandedMemberPath,
};'code'

Comment: No, I can't really rip this out right now. I might when I get some time; for now, this is a must-have, blah-blah and as such has been hacked horrifically (with a chained OnLoad -> OnTextChanged event, the latter unhooked after the first fire). @r.pankevivius: if object initializers and ?? are unreadable to you, frankly, I'm not sure why you're even bothering with this question.

Comment: Also, I'm also almost certain this is Infragistics specific, combined with an ancient bug in WPF that nobody runs into. If I have time, I'll have to do a test to see if it happens with standard trees the same way it does with XamDataTree first.